# How can I specify the symfony version of my project in netbeans?

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans, version

I am trying to create a symfony2 project, with the symfony2.8 version. However whenever I create a symfony project in netbeans I cannot find where to specify the version of symfony and it always creates a symfony3 project. Is there any way to tell netbeans to use the symfony2 version instead of 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd save yourself the headache and time of trying to figure that out, and instead use the Symfony recommended way.

```
php -r "readfile('https://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```

```
# for example, if WAMP is used ...
">c:\> move symfony c:\wamp\bin\php
# ... then, execute the command as:
">c:\> symfony
```

# moving it to your projects folder ...
">c:\> move symfony c:\projects
# ... then, execute the command as
">c:\> cd projects
">c:\projects\> php symfony

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

Net-beans will still recognise your project as a Symfony project along with all the added benefits, but also with the ease of setting up new Symfony projects with one command from the CLI.

[image]

If you really want to stick to the Net-beans way, simply allow Net-beans to install it, however it chooses. Once it's installed change the version number within the `composer.json` file. The biggest issue you'll have for this is you'll have to check all your version numbers are compatible.